# XNA Sprite only Disappears when player intersects

Tags: c#, xna, sprite, collision

I am making a game where a player will go around collecting kiwis. When the player touches a kiwi, I want the kiwi sprite to disappear permanently. So far, I can only make the kiwi sprite disappear while the player is touching them, and when the player moves off the kiwi rectangle, the kiwi sprite reappears.

Here is the intersect function I created in the Kiwi class:

```
public void Intersect(Rectangle playerRect, SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        foreach (Rectangle kiwiRect in kiwiRectangle)
        {
            if (!kiwiRect.Intersects(playerRect))
            {
                isCollected = false;
            }
            else
                isCollected = true;

            if (!isCollected)
            {
                spriteBatch.Draw(kiwiTexture, kiwiRect, Color.White);
            }
        }
    }
```

And then I put this function in the Draw function in the main game class.

```
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {

         GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
         spriteBatch.Begin();

         if (gameState == GameState.Playing)
         {


             GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Green);




             kiwiClass.Intersect(Sprite.spriteDestinationRectangle, spriteBatch);


             Sprite.Draw(spriteBatch);


         }



         spriteBatch.End();


         base.Draw(gameTime);
      }
```

Comment: Hm you don't seem to be using the overridable Draw method on each of your game objects. Can you show exactly where this intersect method is going? Are your kiwis DrawableGameComponents? Or they're simply in a list somewhere in that class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only check if there's an intersection until there is one. You don't ever want to do `isCollected = false` or else the kiwi will reappear.

Your `Intersect()` method should look like this:

```
public void Intersect(Rectangle rectangle, SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    foreach (Rectangle kiwiRect in kiwiRectangle)
    {
        if (!isCollected)
        {
            if (kiwiRect.Intersects(playerRect))
            {
                isCollected = true;
            }
        }

        if (!isCollected)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(kiwiTexture, kiwiRect, Color.White);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Actually, you need to keep track of each kiwi's collected status individually. You can change `isCollected` to a list instead:

```
List<Rectangle> collectedKiwis = new List<Rectangle>();
```

And then change the `Intersect()` method to this:

```
public void Intersect(Rectangle rectangle, SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    foreach (Rectangle kiwiRect in kiwiRectangle.Except(collectedKiwis))
    {
        if (kiwiRect.Intersects(playerRect))
        {
            collectedKiwis.Add(kiwiRect);
        }
        else
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(kiwiTexture, kiwiRect, Color.White);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your method makes them all disappear at once and then they dont reappear at all

Comment: @user2681474 Sounds like you didn't get rid of the ! before `kiwiRect.Intersects(...)`. Just copy and paste my code exactly as it is.

Comment: No, I did. I copied exactly what you wrote.